# Multiple RabbitListeners. One doesn't work

Tags: rabbitmq, spring-amqp

My requirement is to listen to two queues and process the messages

I have created two containers

```
@Bean("listenerForIncomingMessages")
public SimpleRabbitListenerContainerFactory listenerForIncomingMessages() {
    SimpleRabbitListenerContainerFactory factory = new SimpleRabbitListenerContainerFactory();
    factory.setConnectionFactory(connectionFactory());
    factory.setConcurrentConsumers(2);
    factory.setMaxConcurrentConsumers(2);
    factory.setAcknowledgeMode(AcknowledgeMode.MANUAL);
    factory.setPrefetchCount(1);
    return factory;
}

@Bean("listenerForMissedDeliveries")
public SimpleRabbitListenerContainerFactory listenerForMissedDeliveries() {
    SimpleRabbitListenerContainerFactory factory = new SimpleRabbitListenerContainerFactory();
    factory.setConnectionFactory(connectionFactory());
    factory.setConcurrentConsumers(2);
    factory.setMaxConcurrentConsumers(2);
    factory.setAcknowledgeMode(AcknowledgeMode.MANUAL);
    factory.setPrefetchCount(1);
    return factory;
}
```

I have two @Configuration classes to process the messages

```
@Configuration
public class ClassOne {

    @RabbitListener(containerFactory = "listenerForIncomingMessages", queues = "IncomingMessage")
    public void getAmqpMessage(Message inMessage, Channel channel) throws Exception {

    }
}

@Configuration
public class ClassTwo {

    @RabbitListener(containerFactory = "listenerForMissedDeliveries", queues = "MissedDelivery")
    public void getAmqpMessage(Message inMessage, Channel channel) throws Exception {

    }
}
```

The ClassTwo's RabbitListener works only once during server start. After that it is not working -- The messages are arriving at the queue but they are
not consumed.

What am i doing wrong?

Any pointers to get this working.

Thanks,

Comment: Everything looks fine, although you don't really need 2 factories since their configuration is the same. Turn on DEBUG logging to figure out what's wrong.

Comment: @GaryRussell Thanks for your comment. I had two UNACK'd message and that was causing the issue. Everything works fine now.

Comment: Since i am going to have two RabbitListeners, is SimpleRabbitListenerContainerFactory is good or should i shift to DirectMessageListenerContainerFactory. Note: I do not have any requirements for dynamic addition of queues during runtime.

Comment: See [choosing a container](https://docs.spring.io/spring-amqp/docs/2.2.5.RELEASE/reference/html/#choose-container) to decide which container is best for your use case.